# Aggregate Google Analytics Reporting

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have multiple google analytics accounts, each with multiple sites. My goal is to create a high level dashboard that can summarize the common metrics captured on each site.

I have tried using the google analytics API for php and was hoping to get an *aggregated* report of all sites across all accounts...has anyone achieved something along these lines? Perhaps there's a tutorial I missed...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks, will edit the question.

Comment: @monde did you figure this one out? I am stuck with the same problem...